# Function that can recieve different type of arguments

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I'm trying to write function that can receive only data frame contains two numeric vectors or two numeric vectors. But I cannot write if function properly.

```
lad=function(...){
  z=(...);
if (!is.data.frame(z) & length(z)!=2 | !is.vector(z[[1]] & !is.vector(z[[2]] & length(z[[1]])!=length(z[[2]])) stop ('arguments must contain data frame or two vectors')

}
```

Where is the problem here?
function may contain `lad(x,y)` or `lad(z)` where `z=data.frame(x,y)`

Comment: You could also just put the function body into a `trycatch` block.  If the input types be slightly wrong you can catch a warning.  If the inputs cause the function to choke you can catch an exception.

Comment: But I want to check the arguments before the function even starts its calculations.

Comment: If you _really_ need to do this, then check to see if a package already exists.  If not, then write your own helper functions.

Comment: Where is the variable `a` coming form? What exactly is the problem you are having? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Sorry, variable `a` suppose to be `z`. The problem is that even if my input is wrong the function still working, the function doesn't check if the argument is correct. And I can't find where is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally this is done using S3 or S4.   Using S3 we create a generic with methods for data.frame and for default (which handles the other case):

```
lad <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("lad")
lad.data.frame <- function(x, ...) x
lad.default <- function(x, y, ...) lad(data.frame(x, y), ...)
```

lad will dispatch calls with data.frame arguments to lad.data.frame and all other calls to lad.default so if you need to implement further checks those are the places to put them.

In the example above we just return a data frame but in your actual code replace that with something more useful.

Here are two examples of calling `lad` (where `BOD` is a data frame that comes with R):

```
lad(BOD)
lad(1:10, 11:20)
```